# How to use PhpWebSocket successfully?

Tags: php, apache, websocket, phpwebsocket

I try to use [PhpWebSocket](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/) but if I don't add the intended port (say 1234) to httpd.conf (`Listen 1234`), I get:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

But if I do add it, I get this error on call to `socket_bind`:

```
Address already in use
```

It's true for any port (I tried several). I use CentOS 6.

### Edit 1:

Following [Jan Prieser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1496136/jan-prieser)'s comment, I removed the `Listen 1234` from httpd.conf, and the issue is now:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

So I guess it can bee SELinux and firewall, but there doesn't seem to be neither of these.

Comment: check with netstat -antp if the port is bound correctly. it has to work without the listen part in apache conf.

Comment: @JanPrieser: this port is not in use.

Comment: You should have a firewall configured - but no firewall would cause the 'port already in use' error. Use `netstat -a | grep LISTEN` to find out what ports are in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPWebSocket hasn't been updated since 2010. If you are looking for a PHP based solution I'd recommend looking at [Ratchet](http://socketo.me) which is pretty actively maintained.